# PHP Recursive Directory Handle Problem

Tags: php, recursive-query

getSettings() seems to only read and output 1 settings.php file in the directory. How do I get it to read and output all the settings.php file contents?

```
<?php 
$config = array("os"=>"windows","directory"=>"../Core-Stack/Themes/","ignore"=>array('_vti_cnf','cgi-bin','.','..')); 

function getSettings($dir, $issubdir = false) { 
    global $config, $SETTINGS; 
    if ($config['os'] == "unix") 
        $delimiter = "/"; 
    else if ($config['os'] == "windows") 
        $delimiter = "\\"; 
    if (!file_exists($dir) || !is_dir($dir) || !is_readable($dir)) { 
        echo "Error: \"$dir\" is not a directory, or I cannot read it properly."; 
        return 0; 
    } else if ($od = opendir($dir)) { 
        while (($file = readdir($od)) !== false) { 
            if (!in_array($file, $config['ignore'])) { 
                $path = $dir . $delimiter . $file; 
                if (is_dir($path)) 
                    getSettings($path, true); 
                elseif (is_file($path) && $file == "settings.php") 
                    include ($path); 
            } 
        } 
        closedir($od); 
    } 
} 

getSettings($config['directory'], true); 
echo "Theme Name: "; 
echo $SETTINGS['theme_name']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Theme Creator: "; 
echo $SETTINGS['theme_creator']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Theme Version: "; 
echo $SETTINGS['theme_version']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "Theme Creation Date: "; 
echo $SETTINGS['theme_creation_date']; 
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to do the operating system check to set the correct directory separator yourself, you know.  You can just use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant, which always contains the correct seperator character sequence for the operating system PHP is running on

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your "settings" files are defining settings somehow like `$SETTINGS = array(...);` and of course that way you will only see contents from the latest included file. What you could do here without remaking the whole thing would be either:
without changing `settings.php`:

```
//...
elseif (is_file($path) && $file == "settings.php") {
    $OLD_SETTINGS = $SETTINGS;
    include ($path);
    $SETTINGS = array_merge($OLD_SETTINGS, $SETTINGS);
}
//...
```

or if you can change the `settings.php` files:

```
//...
elseif (is_file($path) && $file == "settings.php") {
    $SETTINGS = array_merge($SETTINGS, include ($path));
}
//...


//----in settings.php
return array(
    'option' => 'foobar',
    //...
);
```

That's of course if I got your intensions right. If not - then please edit your question and add more details.

**UPDATE**

also you could use `scandir` to fit the function in less lines and prevent potential problems with heap if the tree is VERY deep, like this:

```
function getSettings($dir, $issubdir = false) { 
    global $config, $SETTINGS; 
    if (!file_exists($dir) || !is_dir($dir) || !is_readable($dir)) { 
        echo "Error: \"$dir\" is not a directory, or I cannot read it properly."; 
        return 0; 
    } else if ($files = scandir($dir)) { 
        foreach ($files as $file) { 
            if (in_array($file, $config['ignore'])) continue;

            $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file; 
            if (is_dir($path)) 
                getSettings($path, true); 
            elseif (is_file($path) && $file == "settings.php") 
                $SETTINGS = array_merge($SETTINGS, include ($path));
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store directory contents before recursion, your else-if block should be like this:

```
else if ($od = opendir($dir)) { 
        $subdirs = array();
        while (($file = readdir($od)) !== false) { 
            if (!in_array($file, $config['ignore'])) { 
                $path = $dir . $delimiter . $file; 
                if (is_dir($path)) $subdirs[] = $path;
                elseif (is_file($path) && $file == "settings.php") include ($path); 
            }           
        }
        closedir($od);
        foreach($subdirs as $subdir)
            getSettings($subdir, true);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter. This way you just eat some memory for storing subdirectories and introduce another cycle. But generally behaviour doesn't change. The problem must be somewhere else.